# Bitwise operations on strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, binary

In javascript the following test of character to character binary operations prints `0` 676 times:

```
var s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
var i, j;
for(i=0; i<s.length;i++){ for(j=0; j<s.length;j++){ console.log(s[i] | s[j]) }};
```

If js was using the actual binary representation of the strings I would expect some non-zero values here.

Similarly, testing binary operations on strings and integers, the following print 26 `255`s and `0`s, respectively. (255 was chosen because it is `11111111` in binary).

```
var s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
var i; for(i=0; i<s.length;i++){ console.log(s[i] | 255) }
var i; for(i=0; i<s.length;i++){ console.log(s[i] & 255) }
```

What is javascript doing here?  It seems like javascript is casting any string to `false` before binary operations.

**Notes**

If you try this in python, it throws an error:

```
>>> s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> [c1 | c2 for c2 in s for c1 in s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

But stuff like this seems to [work in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942540/how-to-bitwise-compare-a-string).

Comment: The spec will explain the conversion. http://es5.github.io/#x11.10 The specific `toInt32()` conversion is here: http://es5.github.io/#x9.5

Comment: Thanks @cookie-monster.  That annotated source makes it pretty clear that in the implicit type conversion `toNumber` is yielding `NaN`, and then calling `ToInt32` on `NaN` yields `+0`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In JavaScript, when a string is used with a binary operator it is first converted to a number.  Relevant portions of the ECMAScript spec are shown below to explain how this works.

[Bitwise operators](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.10):

> The production A : A @ B, where @ is one of the bitwise operators in the productions above, is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating A.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating B.
> 4. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> 5. Let lnum be ToInt32(lval).
> 6. Let rnum be ToInt32(rval).
> 7. Return the result of applying the bitwise operator @ to lnum and rnum. The result is a signed 32 bit integer.

[ToInt32](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5):

> The abstract operation ToInt32 converts its argument to one of 2<sup>32</sup> integer values in the range −231 through 231−1, inclusive. This abstract operation functions as follows:
>
> 1. Let number be the result of calling ToNumber on the input argument.
> 2. If number is NaN, +0, −0, +∞, or −∞, return +0.
> 3. Let posInt be sign(number) * floor(abs(number)).
> 4. Let int32bit be posInt modulo 2<sup>32</sup>; that is, a finite integer value k of Number type with positive sign and less than 2<sup>32</sup> in magnitude such that the mathematical difference of posInt and k is mathematically an integer multiple of 2<sup>32</sup>.
> 5. If int32bit is greater than or equal to 2<sup>31</sup>, return int32bit − 2<sup>32</sup>, otherwise return int32bit.

The internal ToNumber function will return NaN for any string that cannot be parsed as a number, and ToInt32(NaN) will give 0.  So in your code example all of the bitwise operators with letters as the operands will evaluate to `0 | 0`, which explains why only 0 is printed.

Note that something like `'7' | '8'` will evaluate to `7 | 8` because in this case the strings used as the operands can be successfully convered to a number.

As for why the behavior in Python is different, there isn't really any implicit type conversion in Python so an error is expected for any type that doesn't implement the binary operators (by using `__or__`, `__and__`, etc.), and strings do not implement those binary operators.

Perl does something completely different, [bitwise operators are implemented for strings](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-String-Operators) and it will essentially perform the bitwise operator for the corresponding bytes from each string.

If you want to use JavaScript and get the same result as Perl, you will need to first convert the characters to their code points using [`str.charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt), perform the bitwise operator on the resulting integers, and then use [`String.fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) to convert the resulting numeric values into characters.

Comment: Thanks @F.J.  This is exactly the level of detail I was hoping for.

Comment: BTW - The reason for this question was that I found somewhere in our codebase where someone was using `|=` to do input validation.  When I first looked at the code it looked like they were operating on strings, and I was curious how that would work.

Answer (score 6):

I'd be surprised if JavaScript worked at all with bitwise operations on non-numerical strings and produced anything meaningful. I'd imagine that because any bitwise operator in JavaScript converts its operand into a 32 bit integer, that it would simply turn all non-numerical strings into `0`.

I'd use...

```
"a".charCodeAt(0) & 0xFF
```

That produces `97`, the ASCII code for "a", which is correct, given it's masked off with a byte with all bits set.

Try to remember that because things work nicely in other languages, it isn't always the case in JavaScript. We're talking about a language conceived and implemented in a very short amount of time.

Comment: Thanks for the response alex.  I was aware of the `charCodeAt` function but wasn't sure about the `simply turn all non-numerical strings into 0` part.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript is using type coercion which allows it to attempt to parse the strings as numbers automatically when you try to perform a numeric operation on them. The parsed value is either 0 or more likely `NaN`. This obviously won't get you the information you're trying to get.

I think what you're looking for is [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) which will allow you to get the numeric Unicode value for a character in a string and the possibly the complementary [`fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) which converts the numeric value back to a character.

Comment: Thanks for the response squid314.  The information about how the string value was type-coerced was what I was looking for.